# Is it possible to connect to databricks sqlanalytics service from a django app

Tags: django, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

My clients use *databricks* for *data engineering workloads* and are interested in using *databricks sqlanalytics* to service their *BI* requirements.

I want to know if it is possible to connect to *databricks sqlanalytics service* from *django app* (since most of the reports are *django* powered) and if so any link for the same would be really helpful.

I have only worked with *databricks* connect before and this is fairly new to me so any help would be really appreciated.

SOLUTION:

download the simba spark odbc driver available on the databricks site.
set the configuration parameter as required. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi) to parameter setup guide.

```
con_string = ("DRIVER={Simba Spark ODBC Driver};"
              "HOST={};"
              "Server={};"
              "PORT={};"
              "SparkServerType={};"
              "Schema={};"
              "ThriftTransport={};"
              "SSL={};"
              "AuthMech={};"
              "transportMode={};"
              "httpPath={};"
              "UID={};"
              "PWD={};")

 pyodbc.connect(con_string, autocommit=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect to SQL Analytics via JDBC in your Django app.

Comment: i downloaded the odbc driver for databricks connection (simba spark odbc driver). and basically  used the python pyodbc module to connect to databricks. I have updated the question with the connection code